# cartopy - set_extent() extending requested boundary

Tags: cartopy

i'm new to cartopy and still learning basic features.

I tried to plot a specific region however, cartopy extended this region and produced a map going up to approximately 85oN when I requested 80oN. Is there a way I can ensure I only get the region I am interested in?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5.12985642927, 3))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=-35))
ax.set_extent([-100, 30, 0, 80])
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
              linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
```

[PC regional map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcY4w.png)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should make sure to tell the `set_extent` method what coordinate system you are specifying the extents in, in this case:

```
ax.set_extent([-100, 30, 0, 80], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

This method is preferred in cartopy because it avoids having to use the `set_xlim`/`set_ylim` which always operate in projection coordinates, which can be the cause of much confusion when working with projections other than `PlateCarree()`. Using `set_extent` with an explicit `crs` will always do what you expect regardless of the projection of your plot.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `ax.set_xlim` to set the upper and lower limits of the x-axis?  [Here](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html?highlight=xlim#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) are some usage examples and instructions.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know I can pick up some of the matplotlib functions in cartopy.
Yes. Adding the 
    ax.set_ylim([0, 80])
got me what what I wanted

plt.figure(figsize=(5.12985642927, 3))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=-35))
ax.set_extent([-100, 30, 0, 80])
ax.set_ylim([0, 80])
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
              linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
http://imgur.com/a/JYzEm